# Getting JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method:Undefined argument: saa . When using beanshell sampler

Tags: java

I am using below java code to connect to redis and perform certain activity I am getting desired value in the response but my beanshell is responding back with below response message:

ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``  import java.io.InputStream; import java.text.ParseException;  import redis.cli . . . '' : Undefined argument: saa

WARN  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BeanShellSampler: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``  import java.io.InputStream; import java.text.ParseException;  import redis.cli . . . '' : Undefined argument: saa

Please find the below code for your reference.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.ParseException;

import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;


    String host = "ssh.journaldev.com";
    String user = "sshuser";
    String password = "sshpwd";
    String command1 = "${ShardUtiLoc} && java -jar vsb-shardutility.jar -h ${IP} -p ${RedisPort1} -a ${masterauthKey} -m sm:lite -k ${vin}";
    //String command1 = "${ShardUtiLoc} && ${ShrdUtilJarRunCmd}${vin}";
    Integer j = 0;
    try {

        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession("${VSBServUsernme}", "${IP}", 22);
        session.setPassword("${VSBServPassword}");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command1);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        channel.connect();
        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0)
                    break;
                String sa = new String(tmp, 0, i);
                String saa = sa.substring(110).substring(0,3);
                System.out.print("printing sa " + saa);
                // j = Integer.valueOf(sa);
                /*
                 * try{ j=Integer.parseInt(sa); } catch(Exception e) {
                 * e.printStackTrace(); }
                 * System.out.println("printing j "+j);
                 */
                Jedis jedis = new Jedis("${IP}", ${RedisPort2});
                jedis.auth("${masterauthKey}");
                System.out.println("Connection to server sucessfully");
                // check whether server is running or not
                System.out.println("Server is running: " + jedis.ping());

                /*
                 * jedis.sadd("neeta", "200");
                 * System.out.println(jedis.smembers("neeta"));
                 */
                System.out.println(jedis.select(Integer.parseInt(saa)));
                System.out.println(jedis.hget(
                        "sm:{${vin}}:state", "cst"));
                String k = jedis
                        .hget("sm:{${vin}}:state", "cst");
                System.out.println(k);
                vars.put("storedValue",k);
                  SampleResult.setResponseData(k);
            }
            if (channel.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("exit-status: "
                        + channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
            /*try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception ee) {
            }*/
        }
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();



    /*
     * InputStream in=channel.getInputStream(); byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
     * int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
     */
    int j = 0;

    try {
        j = Integer.parseInt(saa);
        System.out.println(j);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return j;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.